# How to recombine text into one line in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

```
=index(ImportXml("https://www.google.com/finance?q=ibm", "//div[@class = 'companySummary']" ),0,1)
```

Put that anywhere in a Google sheet and it will give you a cell with a block of text. This text is in a paragraph form and takes up several lines. How do I use formulas to make it so the text is one line? It's possible because I can do it by hand if needed.

I've tried:

```
=join(" ",split(A1," "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Use the following formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,Char(10)," ")
```

## Explanation

IMPORTXML added line feed characters which ASCII code is 10. An alternative to the use of Char(10) is to add a breakline (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and enclose it in quotes marks:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"
"," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=regexreplace(index(ImportXml("https://www.google.com/finance?q=ibm", "//div[@class = 'companySummary']" ),0,1),"\n","")
```

Using the regexreplace function, you can replace all instances of a newline, represented by "\n" and replacing it with "", thus transforming your string into a single line.

Comment: A little context explaining how this would help would make this a better answer.